# CPU temperatures high on new build after gaming

Tags: cpu, cooling, overheating

My friend had a problem with his computer a while back. His games were crashing, even within the menus. He was stumped as to what the problem was, so I posted on here requesting help. He found out the day later, when his computer would start up but wouldn't display anything on the screen. His video card must have came screwed up. So, he got a replacement.

Now, there's a new problem. His temperatures, which were acceptable before, are now insanely high. His GPU temperature runs 70-80c, which is understandable considering he's running his games maxed out, but the real problem here is his processor and motherboard temperatures. All four of his cores are running at 88-90c after coming out of a game. His motherboard temperature was also 70c at one point.

In terms of cooling, his case should definitely be adequate. He has an [Antec Twelve Hundred](http://www.antec.com/pdf/manuals/1200_EN%20manual.pdf). He's using stock fans. The cable management in his case is very good; better than average. He's using the stock heatsink with the processor too, but note, it was *fine* before the replacement, so it isn't like there's some inherent problem. He has checked the case too. Everything's fine! No cables in the way. The heatsink is seated properly. He turned his case fans up to high, as well, but the temperatures are persisting.

Could the processor be overheating due to running games maxed out? Any ideas?

*Note: These temperatures are only during/immediately after gaming. The temps are completely normal otherwise.*

Comment: Perhaps he managed to dislodge the cpu from the heatsink when he was installing the new graphics card.

Comment: Please specify which CPU, and whether it is running at stock speeds or overclocked. Some other specs might be useful such as case cooling and power supply brand/size. This sounds like a case of no thermal grease or an inadequately fitted cooler.

Comment: The processor is an Intel i7 950. It's running at stock speeds with a stock cooler. The case is cooled by three 120mm intake fans, with 2 120mm outtake fans and a 200mm upper outtake. The power supply is a Corsair 850w PSU. The processor came with thermal grease pre-applied, and the heatsink is, from what I have been told, fitted properly.

Comment: From what you've been told... I'd try a new cooler. Also, should have more exhaust fans than intake fans. A negative pressure inside the case aids airflow over the motherboard. This method is implemented by many case makers. Also, are there nay jumpers on the motherboard whcih overvolt by default?

Answer (score 1):

My first course of action would be to physically check the heatsink. If it's a stock Intel cooler, they can be a pain to get secured as it requires some force to get the clips to click into place. If that fails, try removing the thermal paste and reapply some Arctic Silver or other decent branded grease. Otherwise, get a new cooler. Make sure all the case fans are functioning properly and physically feel the airflow with your hand in the case.

Head into the BIOS and make sure that you select "load optimized defaults" to let the system detect the appropriate settings and to make sure that the CPU is running at its intended frequency.

Other than this, you could have a faulty part from CPU, motherboard or PSU.

Good luck on diagnosing it!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to my computer. I am running ATi X1650 Sapphire (I don't care if it's old, it does a job) and it would crash the game a lot of the times after about half an hour. But after this the whole PC was slow. What I done to fix the problem was the following:

1) Removed the heatsink, used a vacuum to clean any dust and removed the thermal compound.

2) Remove the thermal compound of the CPU, and re-applied it and then re-set the heatsink.

At this point, I noticed that surrounding my CPU, was the 800W PSU and below the CPU the graphics card (which is passive cooled. So it has a heatsink as big as the Titanic). I then mounted a large fan to the back of my case, and a fan to the front of my case. The front fan blows cold air in, while the rear takes it out.

The moral is, check the air flow. As you have replaced the graphics card, I wonder if it's emitting extra heat inside the case.

Also, turn the games down a bit. I'm sure most people would rather their games to run instead of being all laggy and crashy :)

Comment: The games don't run laggy nor do they crash anymore; getting constant 100+ fps with no lag or hangups. This is even with high-res graphics modifications. It's just the heat issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fans are pulling air in the front and pushing it out the back.  If they are fighting each other the air isn't exiting the case properly.